# How to avoid the refreshing of edittext values in Listview on scroll?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I have a listview with 2 textviews and an Edit text. I have used a custom adapter to populate the listview (as I used the same for avoiding refreshing of checkboxes a month ago), my question is how to avoid the refereshing of the edit texts when the list view is scrolled, as I want to save the data on each edittext. Will the textwatcher help in any way to avoid the refreshing and saving ? If yes please help.I have included my the model and custom adapter class here:

Model class:

```
public class InternalListModel {
    String no;
    String name;
    String value;
    public InternalListModel(String internNo, String internName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.no=internNo;
        this.name=internName;
        value="";
    }
    public String getNo(){
        return no;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value){
        this.value=value;
    }
}
```

custom adapter class:

```
public class InternCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<InternalListModel>
{
    private final List<InternalListModel> internnoname;
    private final Internal6 context;

    public InternCustomAdapter(Internal context,
            List<InternalListModel> internnoname) {
        super(context,R.layout.internlistdecor,internnoname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
        this.internnoname=internnoname;
    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView textview,textview1;
        protected EditText edittext;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView ==null){
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.internlistdecor,null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textview=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvintNO);
            viewHolder.textview1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvintName);
            viewHolder.edittext = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.etintValue);
            viewHolder.edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.tvintNO, viewHolder.textview);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.tvintName, viewHolder.textview1);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.etintValue, viewHolder.edittext);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.textview.setText(internnoname.get(position).getNo());
        viewHolder.textview1.setText(internnoname.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.edittext.setText(internnoname.get(position).getValue());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: use can create a custom list (not by controller listview by scrollview , in scrollview the value not be cleared)

Comment: thanks for the clue... is it something like, i have to store all the edittext values in a separate list(array) and then populate the listview? please give me an example or a link to proceed further

Answer (score 1):

You can set the entered text, in the **value** field for that **position(index)**

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    internnoname.get(position).setValue(s.toString());
}
```

That way even when the **Views** are recycled, depending on the position, the **value** will be set properly to the `EditTexView`, because of the below code:

```
viewHolder.edittext.setText(internnoname.get(position).getValue());
```

Comment: thank you ... i had tried this earlier but could not get the required result

Comment: What exactly happens? Does the EditTextView get emptied when scrolled? Keep your textwatcher at the end, after your `viewHolder.edittext.setText`

Comment: Yes the text is shifting to different textviews when i scroll first and on further scrolling the edittext's text vanishes. I tried by placing the textwatcher after setText but there is no change. should i include any code in the base class, something adding any listeners to the listview?